# What distinguishes the terms "relation", "function" and "mapping"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, computer-science, relations

In this context the *first domain $\theta_1\left(f\right)$* and *second domain $\theta_2\left(f\right)$* represent the set of pre-image elements, and the set of image elements, AKA *range*.
The following is from [BBFSK](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D), Part A, Section 8.4:

> An important class of relations consists of the *functions*, defined by the requirement of uniqueness $\forall_{x}\forall_{y}\forall_{z}\left(\left(xry\land xrz\right)\implies y=z\right).$ [$\dots$] The function $f$ is a *mapping* of the first domain $\theta_1\left(f\right)$ *onto* the second domain $\theta_2\left(f\right)$: if $\theta_2\left(f\right)$ is contained in a set $\mathcal{A},$ we say that $f$ is a mapping *into* $\mathcal{A}.$

Apparently that is where they introduce the term *mapping*, and by the emphasis using italics, I assume it is intended to be a definition. Is it correct to understand this as: **the term *mapping* means a correspondence between two sets, or between a set and itself such that the set of image elements is the second domain $\theta_2\left(f\right)$ of a function $f$.  Specifically, for every argument (pre-image) element there is exactly one image element (definition of *function*).  In other words, all mappings are single-valued.**

Furthermore, this distinguishes between the term *mapping* and *function* in that a mapping has a codomain which is not ncessarily covered by image elements, whereas a function ncessarily covers its second domain.

I am particularly interested in this question as it pertains to computer science, and such fields as relational database schema and UML.  I used to think that there was such a thing as a many-to-many **mapping.**  Apparently the use of the term *relation* regarding many-to-many correspondences is consistent with mathematical usage, but the term mapping should be restricted to many-to-one relations, where many may be one.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

There term mapping is just describing the verb of what the function does to its domain onto its codomain. That is, the function maps the first domain onto the second domain, since it is of course surjective onto its image, and if the second domain is contained in another set, we say it maps into that set, even though it is not surjective.

So, a mapping and a function are the same things. Noone defines a function as a being surjective onto its second domain.

As a last note, noone calls these terms first domain and second domain. If we have a function

$f: A \rightarrow B$

we say that $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain.

Regarding many-to-many relations, this is exactly just a relation, and not nessessarily a function, since a function only has one output per input. There is the notion of multi-valued functions, but I wouldn't worry about that for now.

Comment: I was quoting the use of *first domain* and *second domain*.  So, clearly, **someone** uses (or used) the terms as I have.  They occur in the discussion of the theory of relations, where the term function is defined.

Comment: That is true of course. What I mean is that in all of the mathematics I have seen (I have a masters degree), I have never seen these definitions. I would think that the author defines them like this as a start, and later defines them as domain and codomain, is this true?

Comment: I do not believe they ever use the term codomain.  Since the discussion in the context of the theory of relations, the unusual use of first and second domain makes sense.  I might be mistaken, but I believe the term codomain was not in common usage at the time the book was written (late 1950s).

Comment: Aha! See, that explains alot :).